# Not able to disable a field on selection of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to hide an input field based on the selection of dropdown, if the selected value is "Y" input field should be disabled. I am not sure what is going here. 
-followed stackover flow previous question: [Disable Input field according to select option value Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800732/disable-input-field-according-to-select-option-value-angularjs)

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myapp.controller("myController", function($scope){
var orgData = [
      { id: '1', roleName: "VPL", orKey: "SSB", sendAllFundsFlag: "Y", fundId:""},
      { id: '2', roleName: "VPN", orKey: "JPM", sendAllFundsFlag: "N", fundId: "0023"},
      { id: '3', roleName: "VGN", orKey: "INV1", sendAllFundsFlag: "N", fundId: "0026"},
      { id: '4', roleName: "SPC", orKey: "VPN", sendAllFundsFlag: "N", fundId: "0036"}
     ];
     
     $scope.orgData = orgData;
     
     $scope.selectEdit = function(id){
       
       $scope.orgRoleData = id;
     
     };
      
      });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myModule">
     <head>
      <title> CRUD Operations </title>
      <script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js></script>
     </head>
     <body ng-controller="myController"> 
    <select name="select" ng-model="orgRoleData.sendAllFundsFlag" ng-change="disablefundId = (sendAllFundsFlag==Y)">
            <option value="Y">Yes</option>
            <option value="N">No</option>
          </select>
    
    <input type="text" ng-model="orgRoleData.fundId" ng-disabled="disablefundId"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 problems in your select

1) there is no sendAllFundsFlag in your $scope,it should be

```
orgRoleData.sendAllFundsFlag
```

2) values of your input are string therefore you should add ' ' when comparing model with value

```
"disablefundId = (sendAllFundsFlag=='Y')"
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MlDWvr78bJAY70D4I1fZ?p=preview)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would move your evaluation to the `ng-disabled` expression itself. Otherwise you have to have more than one evaluation occur (one to set the `disablefundId` value, and again when `ng-disabled` evaluates.

```
ng-disabled="orgRoleData.sendAllFundsFlag === 'Y'"
```

Also, as [NTP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6453371) pointed out, your evaluation is against a text string, so the `Y` is enclosed in single quotes here.

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myapp.controller("myController", function($scope){
var orgData = [
      { id: '1', roleName: "VPL", orKey: "SSB", sendAllFundsFlag: "Y", fundId:""},
      { id: '2', roleName: "VPN", orKey: "JPM", sendAllFundsFlag: "N", fundId: "0023"},
      { id: '3', roleName: "VGN", orKey: "INV1", sendAllFundsFlag: "N", fundId: "0026"},
      { id: '4', roleName: "SPC", orKey: "VPN", sendAllFundsFlag: "N", fundId: "0036"}
     ];
     
     $scope.orgData = orgData;
     
     $scope.selectEdit = function(id){
       
       $scope.orgRoleData = id;
     
     };
      
      });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myModule">
     <head>
      <title> CRUD Operations </title>
      <script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js></script>
     </head>
     <body ng-controller="myController"> 
    <select name="select" ng-model="orgRoleData.sendAllFundsFlag">
            <option value="Y">Yes</option>
            <option value="N">No</option>
          </select>
    
    <input type="text" ng-model="orgRoleData.fundId" ng-disabled="orgRoleData.sendAllFundsFlag === 'Y'"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```